# How to fix 'Segmentation Fault (core dumped)' error

Tags: c, arrays, char

I am just starting to learn some C so I wrote a small program to exercise on using char arrays. 
It takes in a string from `stdin` and prints it after removing trailing whitespaces and empty lines (if any of you have the second edition of 'The C programming language' it's problem 1-18). 
After hitting the EOF key to end input, however, the program exits with error: 'Segmentation fault (core dumped)'.

I've already compiled with `Wall`, `Wextra`, `Werror` and `g` but no errors are displayed at compile time (using gcc 9.1.1 on Fedora 30).
I also ran the program through `gdb` and discovered that the line that causes the fault is this line:

```c
for (; (c = input[start + i]) != '\n' || c != '\0'; ++i)
```

I'm pasting the whole file since it's a short program and everything could be the cause of the error.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX 100

int Read(char input[], int max);
void ProcessInput(char input[], char output[], int length);
int GetToEndLine(char input[], char outLine[], int startIndex);

int main(void){
    char input[MAX];
    char output[MAX];
    int length;
    printf("W: Max output is of %d chars.\n", MAX - 1);
    length = Read(input, MAX);
    ProcessInput(input, output, length);
    printf("\nCleaned input:\n---\n%s\n---\n", output);
    return 0;
}

int Read(char input[], int max){
    int i, c;
    for (i = 0; (c = getchar()) != EOF && i < max - 1; ++i)
        input[i] = c;
    input[i] = '\0';
    return i;
}

void ProcessInput(char input[], char output[], int length){
    int mainIndex = 0,
        new_mainIndex = 0,
        outputIndex = 0;
    char line[MAX];
    while ((length - mainIndex) > 0){
        new_mainIndex = GetToEndLine(input, line, mainIndex);
        if (new_mainIndex == mainIndex){
            ++mainIndex;
            continue;
        }
        for (int j = new_mainIndex - mainIndex; 
                line[j] == ' ' || line[j] == '\t' || line[j] != '\n'; --j)
            line[j] = '\0';
        for(int j = 0; line[j] != '\0'; ++j, ++outputIndex)
            output[outputIndex] = line[j];
        output[outputIndex] = '\n';
        ++outputIndex;
        mainIndex = new_mainIndex + 1;
    }
}

int GetToEndLine(char input[], char line[], int start){
    int c, 
        i = 0;
    for (; (c = input[start + i]) != '\n' || c != '\0'; ++i)
        line[i] = c;
    line[i] = c;
    return start + i;
}
```

The full output of a successful test run should be:

```
W: Max output is of 99 chars.
asdf   

asdf
Cleaned Input:
---
asdf
asdf
---
```

Instead of that I get:

```
W: Max output is of 99 chars.
asdf   

asdfSegmentation fault(core dumped)
```

Can somebody help me debug this program?

Comment: When the crash happens, what is the values of all involved variables? Do they look sane? There's no out-of-bound indexes?

Comment: I don't know about segfault, but the expression `a != X || a !=Y` is true for every unequal `X` and `Y`

Comment: @EugeneSh. I think you are onto something there, the for loop needs to be an && not an ||. It could be seg-faulting do to continuous looping, thus giving him an index out of bounds when it exceeds the length of input+1.

Comment: Suggest using `strchrnul(str, '\n');`

Comment: @plum0 That's *definitely* a continuous loop. It is impossible for that expression to be false as-is; the two comparators are unique. That loop is a recipe for infinity.

Comment: @WhozCraig the comment was not questioning the validity of an infinite loop being present, but was saying that this could cause an array index out of bounds which would lead to a segfault (since I don't believe infinite loops would do that, hence why you can make inefficient multithreaded while(x) loops for sleeping). This may not be the entire issue, but certainly is one. My apologies for the confusion!

Comment: @plum0 I wasn't confused at all. I was confirming your "could be" as "most-definitely is". I won't say thats the only problem either, but that one will absolutely cause an infinite loop that will eventually breach that array and invoke UB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that `GetToEndLine()` will continue looping until it runs out of memory. Did you mean to use a logical and instead of a logical or? Try `for (; (c = input[start + i]) != '\n' && c != '\0'; ++i)`

```
int GetToEndLine(char input[], char line[], int start) {
    int c,
        i = 0;
    for (; (c = input[start + i]) != '\n' && c != '\0'; ++i)
        line[i] = c;
    line[i] = c; // What is the purpose of this?
    return start + i;
}
```

That should fix your immediate segfault problem.

Comment: That fixed the first segfault. Then another one popped up in one of the for loops in ProcessInput, but that was for a mistype and changing != to == fixed it. Regarding the question about the redundant assignment, I put it in because otherwise the last '\n' of the line won't be included, making the other function print garbage.